# Multipart PUT in PHP (data and files)

Tags: php, http

I have been tasked with building the API for an existing mobile app. App is sending multipart data and files in the same PUT request. As an example, there is /api/employee/personal-info PUT endpoint (notice no ID in the URI) which is a multipart - JSON data and 2 images.

PHP does not have native support for PUT, it doesn't nicely put everything in $_FILES and $_POST so I have to decode the input manually.

I first have to do `file_get_contents("php://input")` which gives me the raw data. I have to use regex to extract the boundary string, then I need to split the input into blocks using that boundary (and regex again) and then decide whether the block is JSON or a file, by looking at Content-Disposition on each of the blocks. If it is a file, I have to regex out the filename and extension, and populate $_FILES array manually.

Json bloks have those headers (inside the body, just before the actual data)

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=model
```

and file blocks only have this:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=IMG_20180208_1.jpg; filename*=utf-8’’IMG_20180208_1.jpg
```

So the Content-Disposition of the whole input is multipart/form-data but then each of the blocks have their own headers, depending whether it is a file or JSON data.

Is this really the only way to do it in PHP? 
Should the PUT endpoints NOT be multipart as a rule when it comes to PHP?
Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd say that PHP's lack of PUT support doesn't make the idea of a multipart PUT less valid; yes its annoying as heck, and means you'll have to write some ugly parsing code, but from the app's perspective its a sensible thing to do.

Comment: Is there any ground rules for what headers should be included in for each block and do they have to have specific format? When you look at the ones in the question, there is no quotes around filename etc, Postman spits out headers slightly different than the ones I am getting from the app.

Comment: There are "ground rules" in terms of the RFC specs (see links from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) but as you've seen, user agents can and do ignore specs with abandon. Presumably you're building a private API for this app, so I'd work with what the app is already sending rather than strict adherence to the specs.

Comment: @Graham I see. I would have thought that there are some specific, strict rules dealing with syntax etc. of HTTP requests. But then, I also thought that there would support for PUT in PHP similar to POST support. I'm not a senior dev by any means, but this took me by surprise. I eventually managed to write a class that decodes and splits the input into blocks and then puts everything into appropriate arrays, saves multiple files etc., but that was excruciating... .NET guys in the office said that they never had to deal with this problem and I am jealous.